# If an n square real matrix has rank (n -1) then it can be reduce to a matrix of square n-1 matrix, with exactly rank n-1

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have doubts with the argument here, so the problem that I have is

> Given $M$ an $n\times n$ matrix with real coeficients and rank $n-1$.
> Proof that you can "eliminate" a row and a column of $M$, to obtain an $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ matrix, with exactly rank $n -1$.

And I want to verify if this argument is enough.

---

If it has rank $n-1$ that means that, there is a basis such that $M\beta_i = e_i$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n-1\}$, and $M\beta_n = 0$.

> Question, given the type of problem.
> Is it ok thinking about the matrix as a function?

Then when restricting the domain of $M$ to the space spanned by does $\beta_i$, with $i \in \{1, ..., n-1\}$, it's invertible, so it can be written as a square $n-1$ matrix with maximum rank.

Comment: Because your basis $\beta_i$ is arbitrary, your argument may not coincide with eliminating a particular row/column of the original matrix $M$.

Comment: The problem does not allow changing the basis, i.e. considering a similar matrix. You should stay with original matrix and remove first one row,  obtaining $(n-1)\times n$ matrix and then one column from the truncated matrix. Or other way around.